# PHP Associative array using foreach SQL query

Tags: php, sql, arrays, wordpress

I am trying to achieve an associative array like this....

```
var $example_data = array(
            array(
                'User'        => 'user1',
                'Today'     => '300',
            ),
            array(
                'User'        => 'user2',
                'Today'     => '40',
            ),
            array(
                'User'        => 'user3',
                'Today'     => '654',
            ),
        );
```

I am pulling the data for the array out of my SQL database using a foreach like this.....

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
echo '<td>' . $user->user_login . '</td>';
$count = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM wp_mymeta1 WHERE value='$user->user_login'");
$user = $count[0]->count;

$today = date("Y-m-d");
$count2 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM wp_mymeta1 a JOIN wp_mymeta2 b ON b.id = a.id WHERE a.value = '$user->user_login' AND b.date_posted LIKE '%$today%'" );
$current = $count2[0]->count;

$arrData=array("User"=>"$user->user_login","Today"=>"$current");

print_r($arrData);      
}
```

This isn't working and the array is ending up with only the last item in it.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try to change your `$arrData` to be `$arrData = array();`. Then `$arrData[]=array("User"=>"$user->user_login","Today"=>"$current");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrData=array("User"=>"$user->user_login","Today"=>"$current");
$arrRtn=array();

array_push($arrRtn, $arrData);

print_r($arrRtn);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$arrData = array();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo '<td>' . $user->user_login . '</td>';
    $count = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM wp_mymeta1 WHERE value='$user->user_login'");
    $user = $count[0]->count;

    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $count2 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM wp_mymeta1 a JOIN wp_mymeta2 b ON b.id = a.id WHERE a.value = '$user->user_login' AND b.date_posted LIKE '%$today%'" );
    $current = $count2[0]->count;

    $arrData[]=array("User"=>"$user->user_login","Today"=>"$current");
}
print_r($arrData);
```